# How can I add transparency to a combined plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a question about how to add transparency to a combined plot. The combined plot consists of three different plots.

First of all, I drew a first plot.

[image]

The code for this plot is

```
\[Alpha]em = 1/137
mmu = 102.8/1000
F[x_] := (5*x^4 - 14*x^3 + 39*x^2 - 38*x - 18*x^2*Log[x] + 
8)/(12*(1 - x)^4)
\[CapitalGamma]totalmu = 3*10^-19
Brmutoe\[Gamma]expmax = 4.2*10^-13

Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime_, s24squad_, s12_] := \[Alpha]em/(1024*Pi^4)*
mmu^5/(MZprime^4*\[CapitalGamma]totalmu)*s24squad^4*s12^2*
F[(mmu/MZprime)^2]^2*(1 + (1 - s24squad)/s24squad*
 F[(1001/MZprime)^2]/F[(mmu/MZprime)^2])^2

cp0 = ContourPlot[{Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime, s24squad, 10^-1] == 
4.2*10^-13, 
Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime, s24squad, 10^-2] == 4.2*10^-13, 
Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime, s24squad, 10^-3] == 4.2*10^-13, 
Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime, s24squad, 10^-4] == 4.2*10^-13, 
Brmutoe\[Gamma][MZprime, s24squad, 10^-5] == 4.2*10^-13}, {MZprime,
50, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", 
 FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]},
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
PlotRange -> {{50, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \
\(12\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-1\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(12\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(10\), \(-2\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(12\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(10\), \(-3\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(12\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(10\), \(-4\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(12\)]\)=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\
\(10\), \(-5\)]\)"}]
```

And then I drew a second plot.

[image]

The code for this second plot is

```
Deltaaumax1 = (26.1 + 8.0)*10^-10
Deltaaumin1 = (26.1 - 8.0)*10^-10
Deltaau[MZprime_, s24squad_] := 
1/(8*Pi^2)*mmu^2/MZprime^2*s24squad^2*
F[(mmu/MZprime)^2]*(1 + (1 - s24squad)/s24squad*
  F[(1001/MZprime)^2]/F[(mmu/MZprime)^2]);

cp8 = ContourPlot[
Deltaau[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 50, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", 
 FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]},
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{MZprime, s24squad} , 
Deltaaumin1 < Deltaau[MZprime, s24squad] < Deltaaumax1], 
PlotRange -> {{50, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}, ContourShading -> {Yellow}]
```

Finally, I drew a third plot.

[image]

The code for the last is

```
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime_, s24squad_] := (s24squad/MZprime);
UpperBound = 1/370;

cp15 = ContourPlot[
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad], {MZprime, 50, 1000}, {s24squad, 
0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {Style[
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(Z'\)]\)[GeV]", FontSize -> 16], 
Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(sin\), \
\(2\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(24\)]\)", FontSize -> 16]},
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{MZprime, s24squad}, 
NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad] >= UpperBound], 
PlotRange -> {{50, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}, All}, 
ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, ContourShading -> {LightBlue}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Blue, Contours -> {10}]
```

When I showed these plots using `Show[cp15,cp0,cp8]` at the same time, it gave me a trouble about transparency of the combined one. Here how can I add transparency to the combined plot?

[image]

Comment: what are `\[Alpha]em`, `mmu`, `F`, `\[CapitalGamma]totalmu`?

Comment: @kglr I am very sorry for missing those values. Now I put all values in the top of the first code. Many thanks.

Comment: do you get what you need if you use `ContourShading -> {Opacity[.5, Yellow]}` in `cp8`?

Comment: @kglr I tried now the method you suggested. But the overlapped line between blue line and lightyellow region became different color. I want the overlapped line stay remained in blue. Is there a better way? But I think this method is also what I want to find as a solution of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: lhcQFT, please check the updated version in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ContourShading -> {Opacity[.5, LightBlue]}` in `ContourPlot` that produces `cp8` and then change the order of objects in `Show`:

```
Show[cp8, cp15, cp0]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to get the same picture without using `RegionFunction`:

```
legendlabels = {Subscript[θ, 12] = 10^-1, Subscript[θ, 12] = 10^-2, 
 Subscript[θ, 12] = 10^-3, Subscript[θ, 12] = 10^-4, Subscript[θ, 12] = 10^-5};
framelabels = {Subscript[M, Z'][GeV], HoldForm[sin^2 Subscript[θ, 24]]};
cp15b = ContourPlot[NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad],
   {MZprime, 50, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
   ContourShading -> {None, LightBlue}, Contours -> {UpperBound}, 
   ContourStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All];
cp8b = ContourPlot[Deltaau[MZprime, s24squad], 
   {MZprime, 50, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
   Contours -> {Deltaaumin1, Deltaaumax1}, ContourStyle -> None, 
   ContourShading -> {None, Yellow, None}, PlotRange -> All];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Append[Brmutoeγ[MZprime, s24squad, 10^-#] == 4.2*10^-13 & /@ Range[5], 
    NeutrinoTrident[MZprime, s24squad] == UpperBound]], 
 {MZprime, 50, 1000}, {s24squad, 0, 1},
 ContourStyle -> Append[ColorData[97] /@ Range[5], Blue],
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
 FrameLabel -> framelabels, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14}, 
 PlotRange -> {{50, 1000}, {10^-3, 1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> legendlabels, 
 Prolog -> {cp15b[[1]], cp8b[[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @lhcQFt,  does the updated version solve your problem?